# How do I transfer my wallet?

Tags: wallet

If I have my wallet on my computer, and I would like to transfer it to a Laptop or make a backup, how do I do that? And also, is it possible to transfer an online wallet to an offline wallet? Like from CoinBase to my Laptop?

Comment: You need to be specific. Which desktop wallet are you using and which online wallets? Coinbase does not provide a wallet service. They call it wallet but it's not a Bitcoin wallet as in a data package that holds your private keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a client, you can just export the `wallet.dat` through an option, be sure to encrypt it!

If you need to move your Coinbase "wallet", you can just send the balance to an offline wallet address.

Answer (score 1):

On your computer your wallet is stored in  under Roaming which can be accessed on windows 7 by running %appdata% transfer the wallet.dat file on any computer on the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a Coinbase account, you don't really have a wallet.

So best thing to do in your case is to create an offline wallet of your choice and send all funds over to it from Coinbase.